# ui-sref and $sce.trustAsHtml

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using ui-routing to drive requests in my angular webapp. In some case I use URL parameters. Now I've trouble if I use `$sce.trustAsHtml(fooModel)` beacuse if into fooModel I've something like this *'Hello! Check this value"'*
ui-sref can't generate href into html tag `<a>`.
It's possible to call ui-sref into $sce.trustAsHtml?

this is working code

```
<div><a ui-sref="secure.foo({val:'value'})">value</a><div>
```

if I use same string above into model and then

```
<div ng-bind-html="TrustDangerousSnippet(model)"></div>
```

where TrustDangerousSnippet, in my controller, is definded as

```
$scope.TrustDangerousSnippet = function(p) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(p);
    };
```

in this case ui-sref can't works

Comment: So in effect you are trying to pass HTML on the querystring?

Comment: If I use ui-sref into html all works fine but if I use this into a model, parsed through sce.trustAsHtml, I've problem above.

Comment: Can you show some code that demonstrates the problem? Maybe an MCVE http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: Sorry, I've edited my question

Comment: Where is the ui-href directive in your second snippet?

Answer (score 3):

You need use $compile first.

```
$scope.TrustDangerousSnippet = function(p) {
  var _link = $compile(p)($scope);

  return $sce.trustAsHtml(_link[0].outerHTML);
};
```